# Is there any console color contrast ratio checkers?

Tags: testing, accessibility

I'm working on automating accessibility testing and right now I'm looking for a console color contrast ratio checker. I know there are many browser extensions, but they are all manual and have graphical interface. My idea of it would be some tool that makes a screenshot, analyses it and gives back a text or image report with a number of violations and their location. The project I'm working on is a React application and I'm using Playwright for E2E testing.

Comment: You can install Google Lighthouse or Deque Axe as CLIs and utilise them to do some automated checking, trying to do a screenshot and analyse it would ne next to impossible FYI as there are differing contrast rules for different page elements (text 4.5:1 controls 3:1 for example) so use an existing tool built for the job! Don't forget that you will still need some manual intervention as gradients, partially covered items etc. are still too complex for tools to analyse.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you open your DEV-Tools [F12] you can see the text color (in Firefox a round circle, in Edge a square). Click on it and the contrast-ratio will be shown.